# Is there a limit to the number of exchanges for rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Could not find anything about this in either the docs or on google, except that it should be bound to the available resources of the server.

Does anyone have experience with really large numbers of exchanges at a time in a working environment? Just creating exchanges should not be the issue (simply until the memory limit is reached) but to use it in a working project with high-message throughput and mostly dynamic exchange creation/deletion.

Comment: I'm curious as to your need for a huge number of exchanges on a single broker. What's your design goal?

Comment: I'm currently scoping out concepts for improving a heavily asynchronous working projekt.
In this instance considering giving each active user on the platform his own exchange for all the messaging needs from his actions and the needed processing. Since the users dont have any interaction with each other this seems like a viable option.

Answer (score 6):

Given how everything else in RabbitMQ is built (and knowing that it's written in Erlang and uses services like Mnesia internally) there probably isn't any hardcoded limit. You'll probably hit a resource limit on your broker's machine before anything else.

If you plan on using non-persistent exchanges (that is, ones that don't survive a broker restart) you could likely create very large numbers of them. Why don't you use the [HTTP management API](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) to write a script that just keeps creating exchanges using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and see how far you get?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i already thought of doing so, but just creating exchanges will, as you say, just get me to the resource limit of the machine but does not really give me insight of how that performs once there is some messaging going on.

Comment: In fairness, your original question mentioned nothing about the performance of them, just if there was a limit. You should either modify the question or start a new one.