# Persistent connections to 100K of devices

Tags: rabbitmq, devops

Server needs to push data to 100K of clients which cannot be connected directly since the machine are inside private network. Currently thinking of using Rabbitmq, Each client subscribed to separate queue, when server has data to be pushed to the client, it publish the data to the corresponding queue. Is there any issues with the above approach? Number of clients may go upto 100K. Through spike, i expecting the memory size to be of 20GB for maintaining the connection. We can still go ahead with this approach if the memory not increasing more than 30GB.

Answer (score 0):

the question is too much generic.

I suggest to read this [RabbitMQ - How many queues RabbitMQ can handle on a single server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989833/rabbitmq-how-many-queues-rabbitmq-can-handle-on-a-single-server)

Then you should consider to use a [cluster](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) to scale the number of the queues