# What are some queuing mechanisms for implementing round-robin queues?

Tags: java, amqp

I have multiple task producers that add work to a queue. I also have multiple consumers that feed off that queue. Since these queues are FIFO, they are dequeued in the same order they were added.

In my scenario, tasks are added to the queue from HTTP requests. Each task is associated with an account and there is no rate-limiting. Therefore it is possible to have tasks from one account flood the message queue.

In order to solve this, I've been looking for a queue implementation which allows me process enqueued tasks from multiple accounts in round-robin fashion for fairness.

I've currently resorted to using Redis with some Lua scripts thrown in to emulate a round robin queue but was wondering if there are any existing queueing topologies that accomplish this?

Comment: None of the answers below really solve this problem. Did you ever find an off-the-shelf solution?

Comment: We didn't find one. We've just continued using our homerolled Redid queue

Comment: I am Facing the same problem. any solution / suggestion ?

Answer (score 12):

I usually do it like this:

- Instead of putting tasks directly into the work queue, make a separate task queue for each account.  Each request puts a task into its account queue, and when the account queue goes from empty to non-empty, *put the account queue into the global work queue*
- Workers take account queues from the work queue when they are ready for more work.  When a worker takes an account queue, it takes out the first task and *the worker immediately puts the account queue back at the end of the work queue if it's not empty*.  Then the worker performs the task.

Using this system, each account queue is in the work queue at most once, and  *all accounts with associated work are equally represented in the work queue*.

This is pretty easy to implement, but you do have to be careful about detecting when you have to put an account queue into the work queue, since there can be two threads making this decision at the same time, and you don't want the account queue to go in twice.

I make it simple like this:

- Have an atomic Boolean in each account queue that keeps track of whether or not it's in the work queue. The worker sets this to false immediately after dequeing the account queue. If anyone finds the account queue non-empty, they can try to CAS this boolean to true, and if successful put the account queue into the work queue.
- There's a small chance that an account queue could get into the work queue when it's empty.  Make sure this is harmless -- if a worker fails to take a task from an account queue, it should just forget about it and take a new account queue from the work queue.

Answer (score 4):

With a [RabbitMQ Direct Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) and [Spring AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/) you can implement a queuing topology that holds a queue for each account connected to a single exchange. Sending messages to the exchange with the account name as a routing key and having a **single consumer** bound to **multiple queues**, the consumer will receive the messages [round robin (see "Direct exchanges and load balance")](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2013/08/21/some-tips-about-amqp-direct-exchanges/).

The problem with this setup is, that you might end up with quite a few queues (one for each account) and at least in my implementation (attached as simple Spring Boot application below), you will have to "restart" the consumer each time a new account comes in, as this means that you have a new queue to attach the consumer to. Don't know, whether this scales / performs very well. Check [this post for the maximum number of queues in RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989833/rabbitmq-how-many-queues-rabbitmq-can-handle-on-a-single-server) and if this might affect you.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RoundRobin.RoundRobinQueueConfiguration.class)
public class RoundRobin {

    private static final String EXCHANGE = "round-robin-exchange";

    private final List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList(   // account(a):task(t) where t holds the expected order of consumption
            "a1:t1", "a2:t2", "a3:t3",                  // make sure, a queue for every account (a) exists
            "a1:t4", "a1:t7", "a1:t9", "a1:t10",        // add "many" tasks (t) for account 1
            "a2:t5", "a2:t8", "a3:t6");                 // add further tasks for other accounts, such that a1 has to "wait"

    private final List<String> declaredQueues = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

    @Autowired
    private DirectExchange directExchange;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer;

    @Test
    public void enqueuedTasksAreProcessedRoundRobin() {
        tasks.forEach(task -> {
            String[] accountAndTask = task.split(":");
            declareQueue(accountAndTask[0]);
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(accountAndTask[0], accountAndTask[1] + " from account " + accountAndTask[0]);
        });
    }

    private void declareQueue(String routingKey) {
        if (!declaredQueues.contains(routingKey)) {
            Queue queue = new Queue(routingKey);
            rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
            rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(directExchange).with(routingKey));
            listenerContainer.stop();
            listenerContainer.addQueues(queue);
            listenerContainer.start();
            declaredQueues.add(routingKey);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class RoundRobinQueueConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        }

        @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
            template.setExchange(EXCHANGE);
            return template;
        }

        @Bean
        public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
        }

        @Bean
        public DirectExchange directExchange(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
            DirectExchange directExchange = new DirectExchange(EXCHANGE);
            rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(directExchange);
            return directExchange;
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
            Queue queue = new Queue("dummy-queue"); // we need a queue to get the container started...
            rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
            container.setMessageListener(new RoundRobinMessageListener());
            container.setQueues(new Queue("dummy-queue"));
            container.start();
            return container;
        }

    }

    public static class RoundRobinMessageListener implements MessageListener {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            System.out.println("Consumed message " + (new String(message.getBody())));
        }

    }

}
```

The number of the tasks is arbitrary in this example - but I wanted to "add the expected" order to see whether the output matches our expectations.

The output of the test is:

```
Consumed message t1 from account a1
Consumed message t2 from account a2
Consumed message t3 from account a3
Consumed message t4 from account a1
Consumed message t5 from account a2
Consumed message t6 from account a3
Consumed message t7 from account a1
Consumed message t8 from account a2
Consumed message t9 from account a1
Consumed message t10 from account a1
```

which I guess is what you wanted...

Answer (score 2):

Any packaged solution will come with a lot of extraneous overhead.  I believe this is the [pattern you want to focus on](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ContentBasedRouter.html).  RabbitMQ has a routing queue solution for instance.  And [ActiveMQ supports this pattern](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) as well.

I would write it myself though, it isn't that hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know that WebSphere in version 5.1 (very old) provided such Queue that a single Queue could provide service with sub-queues i.e. That in your case you would create a sub-queue for each client and basically can then ask in round-robin like manner each sub-queue for a next task. But I don't know the details and in general would not recommend WebSphere (talking from experience). But I guess programatically you can maintain a list of Queues or a Queue of Queues where each Queue on a lower level represents a Queue of tasks from specific client. And then you can use your own logic to take tasks in a fare order from proper queue. Of course you will have to manange your Queues, i.e. clean up empty queues, and upon receiving new task  check if this client already has dedicated Queue or not and add your task to new or existing Queue accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose Guava Multimap usage:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class QueueTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMultimap<String, String> multimap = TreeMultimap.create();
        multimap.put("c1", "TaskC11");
        multimap.put("c1", "TaskC12");
        multimap.put("c1", "TaskC13");
        multimap.put("c2", "TaskC21");
        multimap.put("c3", "TaskC31");

        while (multimap.size() > 0) {
            for (String customer : new LinkedHashSet<>(multimap.keySet())) {
                String taskToProcess = multimap.get(customer).pollFirst();
                System.out.println(taskToProcess);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
TaskC11
TaskC21
TaskC31
TaskC12
TaskC13
```

Also you can add custom comparators for priority management for each customer.